# Ice knife against objects also Ice Knife explosion damage when it misses

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I know that the Ice Knife spell specifically states "the target creature", but it doesn't make a lot of sense given how the spell works.  Why could I not throw it at a barrel, or the ground for that matter, and get the explosion effect.

It feels odd to say it cannot be cast on non living objects.  However, by saying you can attack the ground you make this into a mini 3x3 fireball at any time (barring a crappy to hit roll against a square), which seems overpowered.

Also if the knife missed where does it go?  I don't see it still being in the target square if it missed the target.  I considered grenade rules, but that also seems a bit complicated.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the SE. It would be a good idea to check out the [tour]. The stack has a policy of one question per post, and tries to avoid questions that cannot be answered objectively. You should edit your post to focus on one question (and make a separate post for others), and modify your question so it can be answered objectively rather than by vague hypothesis on designer intent, as otherwise this question will likely be closed until fixed.

Comment: @Carcosa I agree; I like this question, and it's almost painful to put it on hold because of that, but it could do with a bit more focus. Also, Vacendik, in addition to the [tour], take a look at the [help] for more guidance; and remember, when the question is on hold (it misleadingly says "[closed]", but "on hold" is a better way to think of it), it isn't permanent, and can be reopened again by the community; I don't want you to think that your question is doomed just because it says "[closed]".

Comment: @Carcosa: It's not quite that we disallow subjective questions, but rather, we avoid primarily opinion-based questions. It's possible to ask a subjective question that can be answered by supporting your recommendation with experience. That said, this question seems to ask multiple different questions, and at least some of them (e.g. "why can *ice knife* only target a creature?") are [questions about designer reasons, which are no longer allowed here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/33569). Other questions, like "where does a *ice knife* go?", can be answered (by a frame challenge).

Answer (score 4):

## *Ice Knife* can't be cast against objects.

The easiest way to answer all of your questions is just to explain how the spell [*Ice Knife*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ice-knife) works.

> You create a shard of ice and fling it at **one creature** within
>   range.

*One creature* is the requirement, this spell cannot target anything other than a single creature. Why? That's just the way this particular spell works.

There are plenty of spells that don't have this requirement, but when a spell specifically says what it can target, then it can **ONLY** target that thing. That's why it can't target a barrel or the ground.

For example, here are two spells that are very similar in every aspect except damage type, and yet:

- [*Eldritch Blast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast):

  > A beam of crackling energy streaks toward **a creature** within range.
- [*Fire Bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt):

  > You hurl a mote of fire at **a creature or object** within range.

*Eldritch Blast* cannot target a barrel either, but *Fire Bolt* can. Chapter 10 of the *Player's Handbook* has a lot of good information about spells and their casting. If you're playing a caster class, you'll want to spend a bit of time reading this section.

So, after making a ranged spell attack, the description says:

> **Hit or miss**, the shard **then** explodes.

There's no need to know which direction the *Knife* goes when it misses. It doesn't continue on until it hits something - the **instant** it hits OR misses, it explodes. Why? Again, that's just the way this spell is written.

Comment: I don't know that the final paragraph necessarily follows. If the reason it misses is because the throw falls short or hits an intervening obstacle, then it would miss before reaching the target, thus it would not explode in the target's square (which is what I think you meant to imply would always happen on any miss).

Comment: @DaveSherohman whether the knife hits or misses the AoE is centered on the target >The target and each creature within 5 feet of it< so with that in mind it is fairly easy to assume that the knife explodes in their square... otherwise you have a dagger over here and an explosion over there. As far as why the knife never misses their square but sometimes misses them... magic!

Comment: If you're going to "explain how the spell works", your explanation shouldn't be "that's just the way it works".

Comment: He's actually describing how the spell *behaves*... but that is the information of most import to the player.